# Tweaking Windows for a fast internet connection

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

Back in the days of modem connectivity there was a handful of winsock setting that would optimize connection speed. Slow DSL (1.5) negated any perceivable performance increase. The local ISP recently upgraded our equipment and now I'm getting 10 down / .75 up. I'm wondering if I should again look into things that might be optimized.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much needed with Windows 7, it manages connectivity pretty well, most tweaks cause other issues. If browsing is slow, then use some sort of script blocker in your browser, this speeds up page loads by eliminating all the crap websites try to load into your page request.

Comment: Thanks - slow? no - not when moving from 1.5 to 10 times that overnight. But if anything could be optimized it'd be latency. If my benchmark is 10x, I can tell that larger downloads are 10x faster but the avg. web page doesn't scale to 10x - and i wouldn't expect it. But i'd also expect tweaks to help? How about an alternate DNS provider? Tweaks at the (home) router-level?

Comment: I Use DNS Benchmark to find the fastest DNS...http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm